# Camunda and Drupal Integration File Not found

Tags: linux, drupal, drupal-modules, camunda, ddev

I am working with drupal camunda integration.

I have used DDEV for the setup of Drupal. my system version are:

- Drupal version 10.1.1,
- Web Server Nginx/1.22.1,
- PHP Version 8.1.16
- Database Version 10.4.28-MariaDB-1:10.4.28+maria~ubu2004-log.

I have added camunda drupal module using this command and then installed it.

```
ddev composer require 'drupal/camunda:^1.0'
```

Once that is done I have followed the official documentation of drupal of how to integrate drupal and Camunda.

[Step Up Drupal Camunda Integration Step by Step](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/eca-event-condition-action/eca-for-users/using-camunda-bpmn/step-by-step)

**Step1:**

Export the templates from your Drupal site

```
ddev drush eca:export:templates
```

**Step2:**

File needs to be made available to Camunda. Either go to the Camunda program directory or to the root of Camunda's config directory. On Linux, the latter can be found in ~/.config/camunda-modeler. Create a subdirectory resources/element-templates so that you have ~/.config/camunda-modeler/resources/element-templates. Copy the template file from above into that directory.

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/camunda-modeler/resources/element-templates
```

Then moved the bpmn file in the element-templates folder.

**Step3: Import your model into Drupal**
When I import the model in drupal it gives error:

> [ERROR] This file does not exist.

1. I have provided the absolute path as mentioned in the eca:import documentation.
2. BPMN version is a 2.0 file as drupal accepts only BPMN 2.0 files.
3. Given all the permissions to the file.

But still got this error.

> [ERROR] This file does not exist.

I used this command to add file.

```
ddev drush eca:import camunda /home/jadi/my-process.bpmn
```

**How could I solve this Error?**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem you're having is not understanding that the filesystem inside the DDEV web container (where Drupal and your webserver are operating) is a different filesystem. Your project is mounted in there, as /var/www/html, but your home directory is not. I think if you copy your file `/home/jadi/my-process.bpmn` into the project, maybe to the root of your project, then you can import it with `ddev drush eca:import camunda /var/www/html/my-process.bpmn`